# Animate transitions between UIViews in a container view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I have a UIView that I use as a container for four separate subviews.  At any one time, only one of the subviews is visible and the rest are hidden.  Right now, when switching between the views, all I am working with is setting or inserting the hidden property.

I'd like to have some sort of an animated transition to give the app a bit more polish, but can't quite make sense of some of the other posts I've read.

Could someone walk me through how to animate transitions from one subviews to another within a containing UIView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to read about **transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:** [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with this code. This must be very close to what you need.

```
      CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
      transition.duration = 0.5; 
      transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; 
      transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
      transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
      transition.delegate = self;
      [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

      self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; 
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

;